# Authentication in Express and passport authentication

Tags: express, passport.js

How I can implement API authentication on my `NodeJS` Express framework for a `react` based web framework along with option for passport authentication.

Comment: Do you mean authentication of services for React based web application developed using express and mongo?

Comment: Exactly @SureshPrajapati using Reactjs Frontend and Express Backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement authentication mechanism via cookie or session. After successful login you will set a cookie in the browser and on each HTTP req you will have access to cookie data to check for req from a logged in user's browser or not.

Create a middleware function which will check for valid cookie data in req object for each API requests.

If a user is not logged in and trying to access a particular resource by an API call, then request will be unauthorized (`401`).

You need to change your login API something like this.

```
function login(req, res){
    // Your logic for DB checks and to validate credentials will go here

    // On valid credentials, you can set the cookie like this
      res.cookie(cookieName, cookieData, cookieOptions);
}
```

and middleware function which checks for authentication can go like this

```
function checkSession(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.cookies || !Object.keys(req.cookies).length){
    res.send(401)
  }
  else next();
}
```

You can find more details on how to use [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) here.

Comment: Thank you @Suresh but what about redux and passport for login form ?

Comment: Redux has no relation with authentication, it will help you in making your application's UI as a function of component state whereas passport auth is additional authentication mechanism which you have to implement. Refer online tutorials on Express authentication and passport js. Below can help in understanding passport authentication https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-authentication-passport-js/